# How to use Order by clause and limit with union all in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a query where I want to aggregate the results of multiple subqueries on a same table with union all and return only limited number of records.

Sub Query 1 :

```
SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
    AND "bookings"."status" IN (0)
    AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')
ORDER BY "bookings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Sub Query 2 :

```
SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
    AND "bookings"."status" IN (1)
    AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')
ORDER BY "bookings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1;
```

I want to show one record in total from the results of both queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE's to consolidate the data

```
    WITH client_1 AS (
    SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
    WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
        AND "bookings"."status" IN (0)
        AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')
    ORDER BY "bookings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    ), client_2 AS (
    SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
    WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
        AND "bookings"."status" IN (1)
        AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')
    ORDER BY "bookings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    ), consolidated AS (
SELECT * FROM client_1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM CLIENT_2
)
SELECT * FROM CONSOLIDATED;
```

and then sort, limit or where
 only using the "consolidated" table it will have data from both queries

Answer (score 0):

You can order the results of a UNION by using the number of the column in the result set.  So if "id" is the first column returned from the "select * from bookings", you could do this:

```
SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
    AND "bookings"."status" IN (0)
    AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')

UNION ALL

SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
    AND "bookings"."status" IN (1)
    AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')

ORDER BY 1
```

As for the LIMIT, I'm unclear on what you want to do:  show only one record from *each* query, or one record from the results of *both* queries.

Finally, I'm not sure if some detail got lost when you were generating your example, but this is probably simpler:

```
SELECT "bookings".* FROM "bookings"
WHERE "bookings"."guest_id" = 19317644 
    AND "bookings"."status" IN (0,1)
    AND (created_at > '2017-10-04 05:27:29.740508')
```

UPDATE:

if you want to show one record total, then you can just add the LIMIT clause to the end of the statement.  For example:

```
create table foo (a int);
insert into foo (a) values (1);
create table bar (b int);
insert into bar (b) values (2);

select * from foo
union all
select * from bar
order by 1
limit 1
```

Comment: I want to  show one record from the results of both queries.